# django restframework: How to add an array name

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Lets say I have a simple django model:

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

When I display info from it as JSON through the django web framework I get this:

```
[{"id": 1, "title": "hello"}, {"id": 2, "title": "world"}]
```

How would I add an array title to the generated JSON? Like so:

```
["books" :{"id": 1, "title": "hello"}, {"id": 2, "title": "world"}]
```

Comment: You must write a custom serializer. Pagination does something like this, look at the sources of `rest_framework.pagination.PaginationSerializer` for inspiration.

Comment: This is a little against DRY because you probably already have the information about the model on the URL. Your URL is probably something like `/api/books`, so clients can derive the type of object from that. Probably this is why the framework has no provision for it.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use it for when I'm parsing the data from the API on Android.

Answer (score 3):

So your client API requires the JSON to be an object instead of an array (there was a security rationale for it when using the browser built-in javascript parser to parse JSON but I forgot the reason)...

If your client API does not mind the extra fields added by `PaginationSerializer`, you can do:

```
class BookSerializer(pagination.BasePaginationSerializer):
    results_field = "books"

class BookListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Book
    pagination_serializer_class = BookSerializer
    paginate_by = 9999
```

This will result:

```
{
   'count': 2, 
   'next': null, 
   'previous': null, 
   'books': [
       {"id": 1, "title": "hello"}, 
       {"id": 2, "title": "world"}
   ]
}
```

[update]

The security reason for avoiding an array as the JSON root is [JSON Hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/). Basically, a clever hacker could override the array constructor in order to do nasty things. Only relevant if your API are answering GET requests and using cookies for authentication.